# jquery each inside each operation showing error on console

Tags: jquery

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined**

Hi im having a problem when running code that, jquery each inside another jquery each.

```
  $.each(responseData, function(index,item) {    
   var month= responseData['month']; 
 //some code
 var assignmentModals=responseData['assignmentModals']; 
   $.each(assignmentModals, function(i,modal) {  
 //some code
   });
      });
```

Comment: what is the value of `assignmentModals` - looks like that is undefined

Comment: assignmentModals  is another object array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are trying to access each of the elements in `responseData` with the first `$.each` call.

Without seeing your data I can guess that you are looking for

```
$.each(responseData, function (index, item) {
      var month = item['month'];
      //some code
      var assignmentModals = item['assignmentModals'];
      $.each(assignmentModals, function (i, modal) {
          //some code
      });
  });
```